# Is there any solution to execute binary in container that mount from host?

Tags: docker, binary, containers, mount, ssmtp

In my case , I have installed **ssmtp** package on my Unix based host .
Because of some reason , the best way in my situation is using ssmtp binary(under /usr/sbin) on my host to send mail (html file) in my APP container .

I attemp to mount the host directory /usr/bin into container:

```
docker run -v /usr/sbin:/host_sbin --name=myapp -ti -p 889:80 -p 890:5432 myimage
```

and try to execute ssmtp , here are some awkward tries and their results :

*In my APP container and under **/host_sbin***

```
 ssmtp   --->  bash: ssmtp: command not found
./ssmtp  --->  bash: ./ssmtp: No such file or directory
```

So it seems that things are not simple as I think .
Could anyone have done something like this share the solution with me ?
And I'd appreciate if someone can explain me why that not work .

Comment: Found this one useful [https://github.com/larsks/dockerize](https://github.com/larsks/dockerize)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply mounting the binary into your container does not work as the `ssmtp` binary is probably not statically linked. Instead it is linked dynamically to a set of shared libraries that are present in your host system, but not in your container. You can verify this using the `ldd` command, whilch will print all libraries that the `ssmtp` binary is linked against:

```
> ldd /usr/sbin/ssmtp
```

If you wanted to use your host `ssmtp` binary, you would also have to mount all required shared libraries into your container (and adjust the library path and so on; I'd recommend not to).

---

Here's my suggestion: The important bit is probably not the `ssmtp` binary, **but SSMTP's configuration files** (depending on your distribution, but typically found in `/etc/ssmtp`). I'd suggest...

1. Installing `ssmtp` inside your container using the image's native package manager. Do not mount the binary from the host into the container.
2. Mount the hosts SSMTP configuration files into your container (using the `-v /etc/ssmtp:/etc/ssmtp` flag on container creation)

Comment: I really appreciate it , accroding your tips  It seems that mounting all libraries is not a good way . In fact , I had tried a bit of your suggestion before , but what I encountered is SMTP communication port in container,
It seems that  port forwarding with -p is not the correct direction for SMTP  works?
Sorry about my poor capacity , Have you done this before?Thanks again!

Comment: Ignore my question in comment , I just do some stupid thing .
Now it is working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Useful pointer to `ldd` command which was useful to understand what happens when binary is mounted from container-to-docker.